# Birthday of Satyabhama

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, satyabhama

In Mahabaratha and Bhagavatam, Vyasa narrated the birthdays of Krishna, Duryodhana etc., using the allignment of celestial bodies, signs and tithi etc.,

We know that Satyabhama is the second most important wife of Krishna, does any text contains the birth date of the goddess?

Please refer such text

Comment: Vasudeva Mahatmya didn't mention birthday of Satyabhama. I'm not really sure if Bhagavatam or Hari Vamsa Purana mentions this. May i know why you are interested in her birthday or Janma tithi to be precise?

Comment: This is a trivial question. I am not sure why is it required? Even Rukmini's birthday is not mentioned. What about Krishna's sons? Then, I would ask what is the birthday of Sugriva, Vali, Angada, etc., as they are important characters of Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: @TheDestroyer    I heard that Rukmini born in prabava naama samvasthra sravana bahula .... and Satyabhama born in the same year chaitra masam ....

In this video I got that, but donno whether they are authentic or not....

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tC0e8r-9JM&list=PLhFZrcu-dWgn_MHS5eT0o9Sm0F4RfaSEP&index=142#t=4m2s

I asked this question out of curiosity to check whether there is any relation between her birth time and her behavior.....

Comment: Oh! That part is created by Bapu for adding fun in the serial. They didn't say the tithi. Said only bahula and shuddha which are pakshas. So I think that is not important.